# How to bound the value of a holomorphic function at the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis

From Harvard qualification exam, 1990. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a domain contained the closed disc $$|z|\le 3$$ such that $$f(\pm 1)=f(\pm i)=0$$ Show that $$|f(0)
|\le \frac{1}{80}\max |f(z)|_{|z|=3}$$

I am confused with this question because I do not know how to use the condition $|z|\le 3$ at all. I also do not know how this related to the four zeros (looks arbitrarily to me). This question feels really standard so I venture to ask in here.

Comment: What's the maximum of a set of a complex numbers? In any case, the conclusion seems unlikely based on the example $f(z) = z^5 - z$.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The assumption about the zeros of $f$ implies that $g(z) = f(z)/(z^4-1)$ is a holomorphic function defined in the same region. Now use the mean value property of holomorphic functions: the average of a holomorphic function over a circle is equal to its value at the centre.

Comment: Also use $|z^4 - 1| \geq |z|^4 - 1 = 80$ on $|z|=3$.